# How to create calculator like layout in xml and kotlin combination

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I'm new to Stack Overflow. I'm looking forward to making a calculator in the XML and Kotlin combination. I'm aware I should use a TextView or EditText above and RecyclerView below but "how to add 3 buttons in one row in RecyclerView StackOverflow". in all the tutorials I see they show only one element per row. but I have to add 3 elements. I tried to google search "how to add 3 buttons in one row in RecyclerView StackOverflow" but got no good results.

I'm well aware of the working of RecyclerView, so I don't want full code. I just need which part when altered gets me 3 buttons in RecyclerView.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/calcTv"
        android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
        android:textSize="36dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:text="5+4"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_below="@+id/calcTv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Along with the above code, I have a RecyclerView adapter and XML for layout inflating.

Sorry in advance if the question is not clear and for my way of asking.

Answer (score 0):

Add `layoutManager` and `spanCount` attributes to your RecyclerView:

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_below="@+id/calcTv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:spanCount="3"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager"/>
```

`layoutManager` for making the list grid or linear

`spanCount` is the number of columns